# Paramater 'xxxx' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I am trying to write multiple records to local storage using a form that accepts user information. However, I am confronted with the following error:

"Paramater 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type."

My code is as follows:

```
addUserForm!: FormGroup;
user: any = {};

onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.addUserForm.value);
    this.user = Object.assign(this.user, this.addUserForm.value);
    this.user(this.user);
  }

  addUser(user) {
    let users = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('Users')) {
      users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '{}');
      users = [user, ...users];
    } else {
      users = [user];
    }
    localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(user));
  }
```

I have tried setting "noImplicityAny" to false within the tsconfig.json file, but as a result of this, I am met with a new error:

"Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'" on the lines:

```
users = [user, ...users];
    } else {
      users = [user];
    }
```

Any suggestions, aside from editing the tsconfig file would be appreciated.

Edit:

I have also tried this:

```
addUser(user: any)
```

This cleared up any errors I had stopping me from running the application, however, when I tried to add a new user to local storage, my browser logged the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.user is not a function
```

Comment: Don't you want to write `this.addUser(this.user);` instead of `this.user(this.user);`?

Comment: Yes I do - thank your picking this up.

Comment: (that would explain the error : `ERROR TypeError: this.user is not a function`)

Comment: @Pac0 I now receive the error: "ERROR TypeError: users is not iterable"

Comment: `this.addUser` is a method reference which is a function 

the `this.user()` throws that error due to the fact it is not a method/function inside the class or constructor function, therefore it has no callable signature. The compiler is explicitly telling you, it tried to call a non-function

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk : this last error means you are using `user` like an array, but it is not. My guess is that you mistakenly used `user` instead of `users` (your array) somewhere.

Comment: @Pac0 I agree, Angular also uses TypeScript and will strictly prevent misusing something once it is given a type, so you don't mistakenly use a variable

Comment: replace {} with [] in users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '{}'); like users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '[]');

Comment: Also localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(users)); .... its 'users' in the end not 'user'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try defining a User Interface. Something like

```
interface User {
  name: string
  age: number
  ...
}
```

And then set your user object to that type, like `user: User`

Just make the User Interface the same shape as what you expect to get from the form.

Comment: I gave this a try, but was met with: "Property 'user' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
  addUserForm!: FormGroup;
  user: any = {};

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.addUserForm.value);
    this.user = Object.assign(this.user, this.addUserForm.value);
    this.addUser(this.user);
  }

  addUser(user: any) {
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '[]');
    users = [user, ...users];
    localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(users));
  }
```